# Seeing links in email before you click them

Tags: email, hyperlinks

When you receive an email in ICS that has a link in it you can press the link and it will open in your browser.

How do I know the URL of the link before I press it. I know on iOS you can do a long press and it shows you the URL - is there an equivalent feature in Android?

Comment: Long press, select "share", select any text app (SMS, notepads, whatever). At latest there you should see the link, and then can decide to "abort" the action (dismiss the target text).

Comment: Are you talking about the stock email app?

Comment: Yes - I am referring to the standard stock email app. A long press on a link does not appear to have any action associated with it.

Answer (score 4):

In the latest release of Gmail you can long-press on the link and a menu will appear showing you the link. You then have options to "Open in Browser", "Copy link URL", &c.

[image]